# Grammatical correctness of "I'm trying to find what he had written"

Tags: past-perfect, error

I don't know if this is a question which is suited for this site, but in spoken language, does the following sentence sound odd?

> A. What other things did he write?
>   B. **Wait a second, I'm trying to find what he had written.**

I think the sentence sounds fine, but I'm not sure.  My friend had said that it sounded odd, and should be corrected to

> Wait a second, I'm trying to find what he has written.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the author is still alive:

> > ....what he has written.

If the author is dead:

> > ....what he wrote.

If you're not sure, either one will do.

You could use:

> > ....what he had written.

if you wanted to make it clear that his writings had taken place before some other development, as in:

> > ....what he had written, before he renounced communism, he later regretted.

although even there *wrote* would work as well.

Comment: If I were trying to indicate, say, the fact that it was written before what **A** seems to believe it was written, is the use valid?

Comment: I think that might depend on the construction/context of the sentence.